# como volver a cargar un jsp dentro de un div al momento de hacer click en el menu

Tags: javascript, jsp

Tengo un jsp principal y dentro de este jsp en los otros divs jsp que se muestran de acuerdo con el menú seleccionado

cuando entro al index.jsp, carga todo el jsp al principio, pero cuando ingreso datos en el a.jsp y selecciono el b.jsp (que tiene nueva información cargada en el a.jsp) no recarga el jsp

¿¿Cómo puedo hacerlo??

a.jsp
crea marcas de autos

b.jsp: carga un combobox con todas las marcas de autos creadas en bd

index.jsp

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Mantenedores <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#a" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >A</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#b" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#c" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >C</a></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
               
              </ul>
          </div> 

    <div class="tab-content active">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="a">
            <jsp:include page="a.jsp"/>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="b">
            <jsp:include page="b.jsp"/>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="c">
            <jsp:include page="c.jsp"/>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás bastante confundido.

El JSP está en el lado **servidor**. Cuando llega una petición, se ejecuta el JSP y devuelve un HTML+JS al navegador, que es lo ve el usuario y con lo que interacciona directamente.

El HTML+JS está en el lado **cliente** (el navegador web). El navegador web ignora de dónde viene ese código (JSP, Servlet, PHP, fichero estático...). El navegador web solo sabe como trabajar con el HTML+JS.

Los includes se ejecutan en el momento de la petición inicial desde el navegador al servidor.

Así que no es "ingreso datos en el a.jsp". Cuando el usuario introduce datos, el *a.jsp* ya hace tiempo que se ejecutó y para el navegador no existe (de nuevo, solo ve el HTML generado).

La solución habitual estos días es usar JS para que, cuando haya un evento JS (**en el lado cliente**) se haga una petición Ajax al servidor para que proporcione los datos a actualizar en la página. Si quieres una web dinámica busca tutoriales sobre Ajax, o sobre algunos frameworks relacionados (p.ej. JQuery)

Comment: esa es la respuesta que estoy buscando, como hago con ajax una llamada a un metodo de de un jsp/js que esta dentro de un div del index principal, eso es lo q estoy buscando